Are probability density functions measurable?
Question
Let $X$ be a random variable from a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{Y}, \mathbb{P})$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$. And suppose $X$ is such that it's density function $f_{X}(x)$ exists. Is $f_{X}(x)$ necessarily measurable?
Thoughts
Obviously, it's measurable because by definition of $f_{X}(x)$ we integrate it, and only measurable functions are integrable with respect to measure. So this is trivially true.
Root of the doubt
Let $V$ be the set such that $f_{X}(x)$ is $0$ over $V$. Thus ${P}_{X}(V) = 0$. But $V = \{f_{X}^{-1}(0)\}$. Thus to talk about induced probability measure of $V$, it must be a Borel set but that is ensured only when $f_{X}(x)$ is measurable.

"Thus $\mathbb{P}(V) = 0$. But $V = {f_{X}^{-1}(0)}$." Those statements can't both be true, because $\mathbb{P}$ is defined on $\Omega$ and ${f_X^{-1}(0)}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

${f_{X}^{-1}(0)}$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ and not of $\Omega$. What you can say is that $P(X^{-1}(V))=0$. These types of sets $X^{-1}(A)$, are what you commonly say ${X\in A}$.

@Stefan I corrected the question.

@Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the question. In essence even to talk about $P(X^{-1}(V))$, $V$ is needed to be a measurable set, and how is that ensured? By measurability of $f_{X}(s)??$

Well the density is nothing but the Radon Nikodym derivative of the probability measure $\mu$ defined on $\Bbb{R}$, wrt to the Lebesgue Measure on $\Bbb{R}$. The measure $\mu$is defined by $\mu(A)=P(X^{-1}(A))$ for all Borel sets $A$ is typically what is called the "Distribution of X". And the Radon Nikodym derivative is by definition a measurable function. So the sets $f_{X}^{-1}(0)$ is nothing but the inverse image of a singleton set (hence Borel). That is why you write $E(g(X))=\int_{\Bbb{R}} g(x),dmu(x)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x)f_{X}(x),d\lambda(x)$ for all bounded real measurable functions $g$

If you replace $g$ by the indicator of a Borel set, then you get $E(\mathbf{1}{A}(X))=P(X\in A)=\int{\Bbb{R}}\mathbf{1}{A}(x),d\mu(x)=\mu(A)=\int{\Bbb{R}}\mathbf{1}{A}f(x),d\lambda(x)=\int{A}f(x),d\lambda(x)$
